# Code Exercise from "Programming Interviews Exposed"

Tags: c#

This is code from the book - "Programming Interviews Exposed" 2nd Edition - Pages 78 & 79 
- Remove Specified Characters Exercise (continued below)

```
void Main()
{
    string se = "I_am_the_string_to_modify";
    string re = "amthe";

    Console.WriteLine(se);
    Console.WriteLine(re);

    char[] s=se.ToCharArray();
    char[] r=re.ToCharArray();
    bool[] flags=new bool[128];

    int len=s.Length;
    int src,dst;

    for(src=0;src<len;++src)
    {
        Console.Write(r[src]+",");
        flags[r[src]]=true;
    }

    src=0;
    dst=0;

    while(src<len)
    {
        if(!flags[(int)s[src]])
        {
            s[dst++]=s[src];
        }
        ++src;
    }
    string str=new string(s,0,dst);
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

If I try to run this I get `IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.` due to line 18. The author is trying to do the same kind of thing on line 26.

The point is to create a look-up array that identifies the chars that are to be removed. I have a working version of this but I did not use the nested array indexes.

Is there a way that this should be working? I don't see how the nested arrays would ever work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're indexing into `r` (a 5-element array) but looping to `s.Length` (25).

Change line 12 to `int len=r.Length;`  and line 20 to `len=s.Length;`.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a C# program. It's C source code with extension .cs.

In the 80's and early 90's, when we, C programmers, learned C++, we all did this: Think C and transpose to C++. That was the worst way to learn C++. Doing it with C# is even worse. When programming in C#, never think C.

FWIW, here's the [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa336746) solution to your problem in .NET 4:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(se.Where(ch => re.IndexOf(ch) < 0)));
```

Here's a [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f7hht7k.aspx)-based solution (arguably less good because it may fail with some special chars in re):

```
Console.WriteLine(new Regex("["+re+"]").Replace(se, ""));
```